# how to put {% static ' file.png' %} in div tag where both single and double quotes are already in use in div tag

Tags: python, django-templates

In this div tag the double quotes is taken by style and single quotes is taken by url then how i can use single or double quotes again to put add static file in div tag

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the double or single quotes are taken. The django template engine will only care about what's inside the `{% %}` delimiters.

If your editor doesn't understand django template syntax, syntax highlighting might look wrong, but that doesn't matter.

So this template code should work fine:

```
<div style="background: url('{% static "file.png" %}')" />
```

Expected output:

```
<div style="background: url('/static/file.png')" />
```

Inspect the output html to confirm that you get the proper result.

Comment: yes its work fine , its just the editor that highlighting the content